# Return to the beginning of an if statement

Tags: c, if-statement, return, goto

I was wondering if there was any way to return to the beginning of an *if* statement when the user enters something we do not want him to enter. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number1;

    printf("Please enter a number:"); scanf("%d", &number1);

    if(blablabla)
        printf("blabla");
    else if(blablabla)
        printf("blabla");
    else if(blablabla)
        printf("blabla");
    else
        /*I want to return to the beginning of this if statement so the user can try again*/
}
```

I saw some things on *goto*, but I am not sure it is the way to go...
Thank you very much! :]

Comment: no, `goto` is most likely not the way to go! It is used only in very few, very specific things. However you could simply wrap the entire code in a `while` loop and just repeat if the input doesn't match any of your expected inputs

Comment: I would definitely *not* use a ``goto`` for this. I would use a `while` loop. Or break it out into a function and use *recursion* if you're feeling frisky.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen I edited my comment to make that more clear.

Comment: goto is definitely not the thing to do: a do while loop is perfect for your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a while statement:

```
int valueIWantItToBe = 1;//Whatever value you want
do {
    printf("Please enter a number:"); scanf("%d", &number1);
} while (number1 != valueIWantItToBe);
```

Comment: initialize `valueIWantItToBe` to some number in your example, just to make it...,  complete.

Answer (score 1):

Put it all inside a while loop, and only exit the loop if the input is good.

```
while (true) {
    printf("Please enter a number:"); 
    scanf("%d", &number1);
    if (blablabla) {
        printf("blabla");
        break; //good and break
    } else if (blablabla) {
        printf("blabla");
        break; //good and break
    } else if(blablabla) {
        printf("blabla");
        break; //good and break
    }
    // no good and stays
}
```

Comment: ``wile(true)`` seems super bad for a case where you probably don't want infinite loops cropping up...

Comment: I think the intent is for input to happen before the first `if` statement

Comment: @aruisdante: I thought that the point _was_ to infinitely loop until you hit correct input

Comment: Well it meant to be stuck with bad answers. I do not see much a problem.

Comment: added the scanf before the first if, guess that caused part of the confusion as what the code intends. @DrewMcGowen, thanks for chip in!

Comment: Mm, I suppose if the case is that the input isn't directly correlated to the termination condition, then yeah, there's not difference between having to remember to ``break`` and having to remember to set a conditional. In the case where the the termination condition is determined directly from the input @JGrice's answer is 'safer' to programming error (and much fewer lines of code)

Comment: @DonShankin, I tried to have you in my last comment, but there was a restriction that I cannot have 2 @'s :-)

Comment: change to include initializing `number1 = 1;` before first use, then change `while (true) {` to `while (number1) {`.  At least then you have a chance of avoiding the infinite loop thing others have alluded to.

Comment: number1 = 1; (not number1 = 0, or you will never enter the loop)

Comment: @ryyker, did you meant something like 1 is the default in the case of bad input? just want to confirm, if that's the thought, I think it is a good idea

Comment: I choose `1` as an alternate to your first version of answer, where you used `true`.  Because ***true*** is traditionally (and likely) `#define true 1` in many C libs.  While it is dangerous to use it as a condition in a while loop.  i.e. while(true){...} is likely infinite,  using another variable is not.  For example, use `number1`, initialize it such that it will enter the loop (i.e. to 1), and let the user input change the value of number1 to 0 to leave.

Comment: I think going for while(true) here is perfectly fine. It will save you one comparison in the loop and since the different conditions are in an if-block it is easy to break out of the loop in the case that represents good input.

Answer (score 0):

You can restructure a little to use a do-while loop.  I cant get to gcc at the moment, but try something along the lines of:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number1;

    bool continueLooping = true;    
    do 
    {
        printf("Please enter a number:"); scanf("%d", &number1);
        if (successful input 1)
        {
            /* perform some action */
            continueLooping = false;
        }
        else if (successful input 2)
        {
            continueLooping = false;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Failed input */
        }

    } while (true == continueLooping);
}
```

**Edit: some details**

basically, you want to execute infinitely until you get proper input.  So, change focus to always act on "good" input.  Run through your test cases on the input, and for each successful case, you want to chose to exit the loop.

In the case of bad input, don't change the loop condition, so you run through the entire process again

Comment: @DrewMcGowen I can see it being useful to explain what is actually occurring, especially for someone learning simple looping.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to reset the `main()` function when the user enters something invalid.  If so, try this:

```
function main(){

if(blablabla){

printf("blabla");
return false; /* If the code hits a "return false", 
the code stops running and resets the function. */

}

if(blablabla){

printf("blabla");
return false;

}

if(blablabla){

printf("blabla");
return false;

}

return true; // If the code does not "return false" then "return true".

}
```

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int number1;
    int loop_state = 0;

 do{   
    printf("Please enter a number:"); scanf("%d", &number1);
      switch(number1)
         {
          case 1: break;
          case 2: break;
          default: loot_state = 1 ;/*User value is not as expected*/
          }
   }while(loop_state==1);

return 0;
}
```